# get firefox and chrome to align-items: center text the same way?

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox

if i make a div:

```
<div class="letter">X</div>
```

and style it with flexbox "align-items: center", like this:

```
.letter {  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hqm938ak/1/)

on chrome the letter is centered vertically as i expect.

but in firefox, it seems like the space under the text (for descenders?) is used to calculate the centering and the text winds up looking above center.  (this discrepancy doesnt happen with non-text elements)

anyone know how i can CSS my way into displaying this the same cross-browser?

---

```css
html {
  background: #000
}

.letter {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 80px;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="letter">
  X
</div>
<div class="letter">
  g
</div>
<div class="letter">
  Ä
</div>
```

Chrome OS X:

[image]

Firefox OS X:

[image]

Comment: I don't see any difference in rendering of your fiddle between Chrome and Firefox on my machine (Win 10). Could you post screenshots and/or adapt added snippet here to exhibit what you describe?

Comment: In my computer there is 1 pixel difference (literally).

Comment: for me (osx) the capital X in the snippet added by myf is dead center vertically.  the X in firefox is poking out the top of the circle.  they look quite different.

chrome screenshot https://ibb.co/GnfZh0d
firefox screenshot https://ibb.co/WkPbQ9b

Comment: It seems iOS browsers have some trouble as my W10-x64 doesn't show anything out of the ordinary, just like the other two commenters. Maybe, instead of *flexbox attributes* you can circumvent the issue by using `display: grid; place-items: center`, works for me most of the time.

Comment: thanks Rene, trying display:grid looks the same for me, unfortunately.  how can i not have noticed this before?  i guess a couple pixels is usually no big deal, but in a tight space you really notice it.

Comment: Does this all depend on what font is being used? There seems to be some sort of assumption that the center of a lowercase x must be at the vertical center of the overall height - but that isn't AFAIK a rule. The only way I've found of being absolutely sure that you know where a particular character starts and ends given a random font is to draw it on a canvas and look for the pixels.

Comment: Keep in mind that different operating systems have different fonts with different metrics. On top of that even if you provide same webfont even then you can get different outcomes due differences in handling - leading space, line height, visual stroke thickness, sub-pixel smoothing etc etc can differ sometimes.